# Adding a tag to a pagination element django

Tags: django, pagination

When creating a pagination, everything works as it should. Added (?page= page number selection) pagination.

How can I add the pagination page number to its object?

When selecting an object and reloading the page, I need it to be spelled out in the URL (/?page=pagination number).

And the pagination remained on the selected page.

```
class MovieShow(DetailView):
model = Movie
template_name = 'movies/movie_play.html'
context_object_name = 'movie'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['object_list'] = Movie.objects.filter(course__slug=self.kwargs['course_slug'])
    context['title'] = context['movie']

    paginator = Paginator(context['object_list'], 1)
    page = self.request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        context['object_list'] = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        context['object_list'] = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        context['object_list'] = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return context
```

This is how I present pagination in the template

```
<div class="pagination" id="pagination">
<span class="step-links" >
    {% if object_list.has_previous %}
        <a class="page-link" href="?page=1"> << </a>
        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}"> < </a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
       {{ object_list.number }} из {{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}
    </span>

    {% if object_list.has_next %}
        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ object_list.next_page_number }}"> > </a>
        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}"> >> </a>
    {% endif %}
    
</span>
```

And so I have a search of the elements inside the pagination, on which I want to hang the pagination page number.

I really hope I asked the question correctly.
I will be glad of any help!

```
<div class="video_courses" id="block-posts">
{% for c in object_list %}
<a class="a_hover" href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">
    <div class="video_courses_block">
        <div class="video_courses_block_img"><img src="{{ c.poster.url }}" alt=""></div>
        <div class="video_courses_block_text">
            <div class="video_courses_block_text_title"><h2>[ {{ c.author }} ] {{ c.title }}</h2></div>
            
            <div class="video_courses_block_text_navigation">
                <div class="video_courses_block_text_left">{{ c.category }}</div>
                <div class="video_courses_block_text_rig">{{ course.movie_set.count }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

{% include 'pagination.html' %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `if` to the link and specify the page number

```
{% for c in object_list %}
{% if object_list.number %}
<a class="a_hover" href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}?page={{ object_list.number }}">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="video_courses_block">
        <div class="video_courses_block_img"><img src="{{ c.poster.url }}" alt=""></div>
        <div class="video_courses_block_text">
            <div class="video_courses_block_text_title">
                <h2>[ {{ c.author }} ] {{ c.title }}</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="video_courses_block_text_navigation">
                <div class="video_courses_block_text_left">{{ c.category }}</div>
                <div class="video_courses_block_text_rig">{{ course.movie_set.count }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% include 'pagination.html' %}
```